# Connect to MQ using the secure keys (public & private key)

Tags: ibm-mq

I am able to establish connection to QManager using unsecure channel and was able to do what ever I want to do.

But now I am trying to connect to the same QManage through secure channel; I have got the Security keys ( both public and private key ) generate from MQ server but I am not sure how to incorporate the key and establish MQ connection.

I googled and found some answer which suggested the below approach but it didn't work.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","path to public key");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","path to private key");
```

Exception I got.

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException : MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2537'.
```

I would appreciate some guidance or sample code on how to connect to QManager using security key.

@JoshMc -- please find answer to your question below

1. Are you using IBM MQ Classes for Java or IBM MQ Classes for JMS?
   I am using IBM MQ Classes for Java
2. What version of IBM MQ are the jar files you are using from?

   Version 7
3. What version of MQ is the queue manager you are attempting to connect to?

   Version 8
4. Are you attempting to have MQ validate a client cert (Check the value of SSLCAUTH on the SVRCONN channel)

   Yes. I have public and private key generated from MQ server by MQ Admin (I have no access to MQ server) and need to use it to connect to the MQ server.
5. Paste any errors that show up in the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG when you attempt to connect.

I don't have access to the log file.

Below is working code; I am able to connect to unsecure channel and send message

public void MQSender(){

```
MQQueueManager QMgr = null; 

    try {

   MQEnvironment.hostname = "hostname"; 

   MQEnvironment.channel = "UNSECURE"; 
   //MQEnvironment.channel = "SECURE";

   MQEnvironment.port = 8080;
   QMgr = new MQQueueManager("QManager");

       int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT;
       MQQueue queue = QMgr.accessQueue("QNAME",openOptions);

       MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
       pmo.options = MQConstants.MQPMO_LOGICAL_ORDER | MQConstants.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;

       MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
       message.writeString("TEST");
       queue.put(message, pmo);

    QMgr.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        if(QMgr!=null){

    try {

        QMgr.backout();

    } catch (MQException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
         }

       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: Please click the "edit" link under your question and add some more details. 
 1. Are you using IBM MQ Classes for Java or IBM MQ Classes for JMS?  2. What version of IBM MQ are the jar files you are using from?  3. What version of MQ is the queue manager you are attempting to connect to?  4. Are you attempting to have MQ validate a client cert (Check the value of SSLCAUTH on the SVRCONN channel) 5. Paste any errors that show up in the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG when you attempt to connect.  Provide a minimal sample of code that works without TLS and the code that fails with TLS.

Comment: @JoshMc - please find my answer to your question. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide specific versions.

Comment: @JoshMc -- which version?.  MQ Manager I see in properties is 08000005 and MQ Java class version is 7.0.1.4.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full versions.   What jre are you using?  Which ciphersuite are you using?  Which cipherspec is set on the svrconn channel?

Comment: Raj, you should not destroy the original question because you found an answer, you should either accept an answer provided if it resolved your problem, possibly updating your original question with a Resolution describing what you did, or if the answer(s) did not help, then post your own answer describing how you fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the option specifying the ciphersuite to use from your code:
MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite

This knowledge center article may help: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031220_.htm

And do you have your trusted certs and private cert/key pair in JKS stores?
These should be more like:

> System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","path to JKS file containing certificates required to validate server certificate");
>
> System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","path to JKS file containing certificate and private key of the client");